# Trouble with iterator in Java

Tags: java, iterator

First of all, and in order for you to understand this question, i'm going to briefly explain my project:

I have a class named `Pair`, which basically creates the type

```
Pair<String,Double>
```

and has a `getFirst()` and `getSecond()` methods for returning the `String` and `Double` values respectively.

Then i have another class, named `Package`, which basically consists in a list of `Pairs`, and implements the `Iterable` interface, so i can iterate trough the list:

```
Package<Pair<String,Double>> package;
List <Pair<String,Double>> list;
```

What i want is to `sum` the `doubles` on each `Pair`, using the `iterator()`.

The iterator is defined like this for the `Package` class:

```
public Iterator<E> iterator() {

        return this.iterator();
    }
```

I've tried two different approaches, which in both cases resulted in a:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at Package.iterator(Package.java:98)
```

Here's the first one:

```
public static double packageWeight(Package<Pair<String, Double>> package) {

    double sum = 0;
    Pair<String, Double> pair;

    while (package.iterator().hasNext()) {

        pair = package.iterator().next();
        sum = sum + pair.getSecond();

    }

    return sum;
}
```

And the second one:

```
public static double packageWeight(Package<Pair<String, Double>> package) {

    double sum = 0;
    Pair<String, Double> pair;

    Iterator<Pair<String,Double>> it = Package.iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {

        pair = it.next();
        sum = sum + pair.getSecond();

    }

    return sum;
}
```

My question is:
 What am i doing wrong in order to get this error?

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code?

Comment: Also, don't you need to pass the iterator an object to iterate over? In the packageWeight method...

Comment: You can't have a variable called `package`, surely? It's a java keyword.

Comment: You also can't be invoking `Package.iterator()` unless you make it `static`.

Comment: The first code is fundamentally wrong anyway. You'll always get a new  iterator (at least if its correctly implemented), so you should have an infinite loop. Also since you perform a read-only operation, let your class implement the `Iterable` interface and use a for-each. That will be less error prone...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The immediate cause of the `StackOverflowError` is that you are invoking the method in itself:

```
public Iterator<E> iterator() {

        return this.iterator();
    }
```

You need to invoke a different method here, e.g. `return list.iterator()` or `package.iterator()` (except that `package` is not a valid identifier in Java, since it is a keyword).

Comment: yes! Indeed the problem was solved using my second approach and changing the return status to `list.iterator()`, thanks!

Comment: about the `package.iterator()` problem, i was just translating the question to english, and it turned out to look like i had a problem there! the original name is different though

Answer (score 2):

Your first attempt is flawed because you are requesting a new iterator each time you call `package.iterator()` - I think you knew that because you then wrote the second one.

The fault with the second is more subtle - you need to use `package.iterator()` not `Package.iterator()`. The second should not work anyway.

And what [Andy Turner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29493709/823393) said.